# How to get html textbox value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I dynamically created a textbox in php:

```
echo '<td><input name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" type="text" /> </td>';
```

Now i wanna pass the value of this textbox in javascript funcion. I have a updatebutton and i am passing the value on the onclick event, but it is not working. Here is my updatebutton code:

```
echo '<td><input id="btnUpdate" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value =  "Update" onclick="updateButton(' . document.getElementsByName('txtEmail')[0].value . ')" /> </td>';
```

Here is my JavaScript function:

```
function updateButton(custEmail)
{ alert (custEmail); }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ??? check your browser console.

Comment: You're calling the JavaScript as if it were PHP, which it's not.  Use `onclick="updateButton(document.getElementsByName(\'txtEmail\')[0].value)"` instead.

Comment: I have array of textboxes, could you plz advise me that how can i get the value of current textbox. How can i get the index of current textbox

Answer (score 1):

Don't concatenate your JavaScript function into the echo statement. Do this -

```
echo '<td><input id="btnUpdate" type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value =  "Update" onclick="updateButton(document.getElementsByName(\'txtEmail\')[0].value)" /> </td>';
```

If you would code your PHP with error checking on you would have seen the syntax problems. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I have array of textboxes, could you plz advise me that how can i get the value of current textbox. How can i get the index of current textbox

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing JS and PHP code:

```
echo '....' . document.getEtc...
^^^^^^^^--php    ^^^^^^----javascript
```

This is literally impossible. PHP executes on the server, Javascript executes on the client. There is NO need to "break out" of your PHP string at all:

```
echo '<td>...onclick="updateButton(document.getElementsByName(\'etc...';
```